# How to control function execution which is called repeatedly based on parameter values supplied to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this requirement where I want to execute function based on parameter values as explained below.
This function in my file FileA.js is being called in loop repeatedly from some external file and source code of external file is not in my control i.e. I cant change how function is called.

```
//FileA.js
function myfunction(param1 , param2, param3 ){

   /* function logic */
}
```

I am specifically looking at two values in param3 suppose 'xyz' and 'abc'. If 'abc' value comes first, I want to wait till 'xyz' value comes in param3 and execute function such that first its executed for value 'xyz' and then 'abc'. Please help not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation using first class functions and javascript closures :

```
// declare an additional queue to pile up commands as nessecary
let queue = [] 


// since you have no control over this function invocation, leaving it 
// as is
function myFunction(param1, param2, param3){
  // call the queueing logic right away
  queueingLogic(param1,param2,param3)
}

function queueingLogic(param1, param2, param3){
  // if param3 is 'abc' queue
  if(param3 ==='abc'){
    // the queue will recieve a function declaration, rather than the execution of the function
    queue.push(actualLogic(param1,param2,param3))
  }
  // else execute the logic and execute the rest of the pending tasks
  if(param3 === 'xyz'){
    // execute your actual logic for 'xyz'
    actualLogic(param1,param2,param3)();
    // loop through the queue, executing the functions
    queue.forEach(pending => pending())
    // empty the queue, since all has been executed
    queue = []
  }
}

function actualLogic(param1, param2, param3){
  // create a javascript closure to delay invocation
  // you will be returning a function declaration, and it will be invoked later
  return function(){
    console.log(param1, param2, param3)
    // your actual logic here
  }
}


//testing
myFunction('1st call', 'param21', 'abc')
myFunction('2nd call', 'param22', 'abc')
myFunction('3rd call', 'param23', 'abc')
myFunction('4th call', 'param24', 'xyz')
```

Output :

```
4th call param24 xyz
1st call param21 abc
2nd call param22 abc
3rd call param23 abc
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.